# Intern test framework - Making a REST API call

Tags: rest, chaining, intern

I am trying to make a REST API call as below and once the call is complete, I want to print "Done". 
But with the below example "Done" is getting printed even before the REST call is complete.

```
     return this.remote
            .then(function() {
                request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
                      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
                      }
                    })
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Done")
            })
```

Am I missing something here? If this not the right way, could someone please let me know what the right way is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Leadfoot (the library that Intern uses to drive functional tests) to keep track of an asynchronous operation, asynchronous operations in `then` callbacks should return Promises (or thenables). Luckily, `request` returns a promise, so just do:

```
.then(function () {
    return request('...', function (...) {
       ...
    });
})
```